# How to remove TypeScript type annotations but preserve formatting?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, prettier

I have TS project and want to erase all types from it but preserve formatting.

```
tsc -t es2018 -o js
```

Works fine, but all empty lines are deleted, eslint --fix, prettier, standard --fix doesn't restore empty lines.

It there are way around this?

Comment: this is a very uncommon to downgrade TS to JS. Are you sure you do the right thing?

Comment: You could try the [Babel TypeScript plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-typescript.html) and see if it is any better about preserving formatting.

Comment: I'm sure about what I'm doing.

Answer (score 5):

The [detype](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detype) package has reasonably well-formatted output, especially if you're already using Prettier for auto-formatting.

> DISCLAIMER: I am the author of this tool.